# React TS prop arrow function not being called inside a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a parent component that store a use state of whether the mobile Nav is open or not `const [showMobileMenu,setShowMobileMenu] = useState<boolean>(false);` and I created an arrow function to set it to false and passing it down to a child component like this:

```
const closeMobileMenu =():void=>{
  setShowMobileMenu(false);
}
```

(...inside the return)

```
<MobileMenu closeMenu={closeMobileMenu}/>
```

Inside the child component I am setting the correct props like this:

```
interface Props{
    closeMenu: MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>,
}
```

If I am using an `img` tag the `onClick` works perfectly fine like this:
`<img src={close} alt="" onClick={props.closeMenu}/>`

However I am now trying to call it inside an `onClick` button function like this and its not being called :

`<button onClick={(click)=>redirectUser(click,'/register')}>Join Us</button>` 
function:

```
    function redirectUser(event:MouseEvent, url:string):void{
        navigate(url);
        //THIS ISNT WORKING 
        props.closeMenu;
    }
```

The User gets redirected to the correct page however the `closeMenu` function never gets called as the men u stays open and I don't get any errors. Hopefully I explained this well enough. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function - add () after `props.closeMenu`

Comment: At least show the code for that?

Comment: I just get an error when I add them as its just an arrow function with no arguments - "An argument for 'event' was not provided."

Comment: Does it work if you pass `event` as the argument? You probably don't need it though since it seems you aren't using it anywhere. I would change the type signature of closeMenu to `() => void`, then remove all references to the event parameter. It is perfectly fine to supply a parameter-less function to the onClick handler. So `redirectUser` would only have `url` as its single parameter.

Comment: Props.closeMenu()

Comment: I changed the closeMenu to void and added the () to when im calling it and it now works perfectly thanks @wasmachien, if u type it as an answer ill accept it for u thanks